# When does Windows 8 Reader app save the current position in the opened PDF file?

Tags: windows-8, pdf, pdf-reader

I'm reading a lot of PDF books in the built-in Windows 8 Reader app (now in Windows 8.1). Sometimes it saves the current position when I close a file but sometimes not. Can anybody tell me when this app should store the current page so it can automatically open the document on the position I ended reading the last time?

One observation from my side: if I open a PDF file by double-clicking it in Windows Explorer, it seems it is opened from the first page every time, but if I use the built-in Reader's Browse dialog, the position is restored properly.

Comment: Its likely stored in the pdf file itself.  Make sure you always close the reader the same way.

Comment: @Ramhound, Do I need to close the whole reader (ALT+F4) or each file personally with say CtRL+W?